Powershell text file to columns, subset and add columns for new output
I have a tab delimited "csv" file but the first 20 lines are metadata to ignore before the headings and data. There is also a line of units between the heading and data I want to use.
L   Acme Labs
O   Acme Solutions
W   12/12/2000
H   ID   Name   Data1     Data2
U                     %            cm
D   001  S1       20.5      12
.
.
For each data column I want to output
ID   Name   Data   Value   Unit
001  S1       Data1   20.5   %
ID   Name   Data   Value   Unit
001  S1       Data2   12   cm
So far I can

read headings and units lines separately

$headings = Select-string $input -Pattern "^H"


read all the heading and data lines

$data = Select-string $input -Pattern "^(H|D)"

I was hoping Powershell has a way to let me do this

select subsets of columns for output
insert columns and assign a value
get and rename headings

Are tables the way to do this?

$data = Select-string $input -Pattern "^(H|D)"
$data | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter `t

